# Storing not-really-sensitive data in JSON

Tags: json, .htaccess

I am generating tokens for files stored on my server, and these tokens are not used for any sensitive data. they're just there to protect from accessing to the real files.

Example:

```
image.png?id=(file id)&token=(temp token) => path/to/secret-directory/TheRealPNGFile.png
```

The file is being parsed by server side script, and the tokens are stored in JSON, which is protected by apache:

```
require all denied
```

I was wondering if it's okay to do something like that? Is it safe to store these tokens, even they're not linking to any sensitive data (only user-uploaded images and videos) or should I store them in a real DB? Of course, the user can not know the real file name, since i'm using an id which leads to the actual file. this ID is not stored anywhere - it's using a function in my script which detecting this file.

Comment: You should consider if it's a protection for you (others cannot get access to data) or is it a protection of data which belongs to other people. In first case it may be ok. In the second case I would suggest encoding the data inside the json-files before writing (e.g. logins, passwords .. etc.) and decoding after reloading.

Comment: @Melvin Thanks for your answer. I guess it's for the website. It's like the way facebook works - they have token and it expires after some time, but the video/photo is shown always (but with new token, and new expiration date). It should protect the real paths